# Almost complex structure question

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I know that if $M$ admits an almost complex structure $J$, then $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}(M)=2k$, thus every odd-dimensional manifold doesn't admit an almost complex structure. My question is, are there even-dimensional, orientable manifolds that don't admit an almost complex structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many.

> **Theorem** (Borel-Serre) The only spheres $S^n$, $n > 0$, that admit an almost complex structure are $S^2$ and $S^6$.

As you surely know, $S^2$ admits a complex structure, and the sphere endowed with that structure is usually called the *Riemann sphere*. Whether $S^6$ admits a complex structure is an open question (but see, e.g., [this thread on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1973/is-there-a-complex-structure-on-the-6-sphere)); the usual almost complex structure on $S^6$, inherited from the octonion algebra, is nonintegrable.

> Borel, A., Serre, J.-P. "Groupes de Lie et puissances réduites de Steenrod." *Amer. J. Math.* **75** (1953), 409–448.

A modern, self-contained presentation of a proof can be found in these [recent talk notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.03883).

Comment: I think in the statement of your theorem, you want an *almost* complex structure.

Comment: Yes, that was my intent. Thanks for pointing it out!